# elastic search query filter out ids by wildcard

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I'm hoping to create a query where it will filter out IDs containing a wildcard.  For instance, I would like to search for something everywhere except where the ID contains the word current. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. Sounds like a NOT query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible using [Regex Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-filter.html)/[Regex Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html). I could not figure a way to directly do it using the Complement option hence I've used `bool` `must_not` to solve your problem for the time being. I'll refine the answer later if possible.

```
POST <index name>/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must_not": [
            {
               "regexp": {
                  "ID": {
                     "value": ".*current.*"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```