# How to filter out (exclude) all results given by Elastic search query DSL in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

I'm trying to view a list of user agents connecting to my web server.
I wrote this (working) query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "useragent": {
        "value": "Mozilla/5.0 \\(Windows.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But while I was trying to get the Invert match (similar to -v in Grep) couldn't find the answer.

I saw this post - 
[elastic search query filter out ids by wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878959/elastic-search-query-filter-out-ids-by-wildcard)
But it didn't work - tryied copy pase, only filter, only must_not, with and without bool,  with and without match_all.

I also searched in Google for the answer with no luck.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `must_not` clause of [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "useragent": {
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 \\(Windows.*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```